# For loop to sum multiple arrays into one array

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, iteration

How would one add multiple arrays such as those posted below into one array using a for loop. Each array would be accessed via an individual csv file.Lets say file names would be array1.csv, array2.csv...array70.csv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXWxU.png)

Comment: Can you provide some code? Have you tried something yet? Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Ahh yes sorry never posted before. Iam using Python. My code is similar to this but it only adds the last array.

Comment: empty = np.full((512, 512),0)

for filename in files1:
    file = filename
    df = pd.read_csv('C://Users//csv//'+file )
    summed_arrays = np.add(empty,df)